# Column Formatting using JSON: Get value of the column "CheckoutUser"

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, formatting

I´m trying to check the value of the column "CheckoutUser" with json.

```
""style": {
    "min-height": "35px",
    "margin-top": "6px",
    "display": "=if([$CheckoutUser] != null, 'block', 'none')"
}"
```

The internalname of the column is `"CheckoutUser"` but it wont work.

Retrieving the value of `"_ModerationStatus"` works great with the same expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code works for me:

```
"display": "=if([$CheckoutUser.email] != '', 'block', 'none')"
```

Since it's a user field, you can check email for a blank value (`$CheckoutUser.id` seems also works).

And of course, don't forget to add "Checked Out To" to a view.